# Excel VBA - Copy method of Worksheet class failed

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy sheets from VBA. Here is my code:

```
'Create a new excel workbook and copy two result sheets.
Public Function copyAsSaveResultSheets(filePath As String)

    'Remove alert for confirmations
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Get new work book
    Dim newWorkBook As Workbook
    Set newWorkBook = Workbooks.Add

    'Copy result sheet
    'When click "Debug" cursor is here.
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ResultProcess").Copy Before:=newWorkBook.Sheets(1)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ResultCode").Copy Before:=newWorkBook.Sheets(1)

    'Delete default sheet
    For Each sheet In Worksheets
        Select Case sheet.Name
            Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"
                sheet.Delete
        End Select
    Next

    'Save work book
    newWorkBook.SaveAs filePath

    'Close new work book
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    'Available showing alert from application
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Function
```

When running this code, I get this error:

[image]

[image]

I didn't find any error in my code. The "ResultProcess" sheet and "ResultCode" sheet are protected according to requirement. Does this matter?

Comment: you might need to read this : https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-bdb8252f-d605-45cb-9712-137925867ad4

Comment: Yes keong, I only protect all cell from worksheets. Is does matter? I don't see any fault. Can you explain me clearly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you need unprotect the cell before copy the worksheet. Other than that, please check whether you got the permission to copy or not.

Comment: I tried with Unprotect. But it is not worked. How to check permission. Can you tell me? Thanks

Comment: This might help you : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Restrict-permission-to-content-in-a-file-3cdd7eda-79d4-471f-91af-4dd02cc6f764

Comment: Fri, I am OK with this code doing nothing. I thinked that is caused of EXCEL APPLICATION. Now, I am finiding tha cause of failure. Thanks for your help..!

Comment: Try copying manually. On my machine, when a sheet is protected and I right click the sheet name, the "copy" option is grayed out, i.e. unavailable. Consequently, VBA will fail at this.

Comment: Yes, right. I also find that error. I exactly know that cause of Application. Not of code. If you anything, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you not simply unprotect it, then copy and then protect again?

Comment: I did it. But not ok?

Comment: This problem is Ok when restarting the excel application. I don't know why. Just restart the excel application. It is OK.